# Issue with subcommands: ctx.invoked_subcommands is always None

Tags: python, python-3.5, discord, discord.py

**EDIT: A solution has been found**

> Try changing the names of the subcommands to `_enabled` and `_disabled` and pass `name="enabled"` `name="disabled"` to the command decorators. This is a guess, but sometimes names that the Bot uses internally don't work properly when used as command names. **- Patrick Haugh**

I tried to clean up a bit of code and tried to implement subcommands into a module, but i hit a problem that i can't seem to solve.
First,  here is the code:

```
@commands.group()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def autorole(self, ctx):
    exists = dbinteraction.dbexec("SELECT role from autorole WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id))
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        em = None
        if (exists == None):
            em = discord.Embed(title="Autorole is disabled for this guild.", color=discord.Color(0xff0000))
        else:
            em = discord.Embed(title="Autorole is enabled for this guild.", color = discord.Color(0x32ff00))
            rol = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=exists)
            em.add_field(name="Current role:", value=rol.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)

@autorole.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def enabled(self, ctx, role: discord.Role=None):
    """Defines a role that will be applied to all new members, format: autorole (enabled/disabled) [role]"""
    exists = dbinteraction.dbexec("SELECT role from autorole WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id))
    print('status, role : {} {}'.format("enabled", role.id))
    try:
        if role==None:
            await ctx.send("No role provided")
        else:
            if (exists!=None):
                dbinteraction.dbexec("UPDATE autorole SET role = {}".format(role.id))
            else:
                dbinteraction.dbexec("INSERT INTO autorole VALUES({},{})".format(ctx.guild.id, role.id))
                em = discord.Embed(title="", color= discord.Color(0x32ff00))
                em.add_field(name="Autorole enabled", value="Current role: {}".format(role.mention))
                await ctx.send(embed=em)

    except (Exception) as e:
        print(e)

@autorole.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def disabled(self, ctx, role: discord.Role=None):
    exists = dbinteraction.dbexec("SELECT role from autorole WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id))
    print('disab')
    if(exists!=None):
        dbinteraction.dbexec("DELETE FROM autorole WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.server.id))
        await ctx.send("Autorole disabled")
```

No matter what i tried, the following bit of code always executes the default command ( the one after `if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:` ), **I am using the rewrite**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [`invoke_without_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Group.invoke_without_command).  It's a parameter you pass to your group that tells it to only run the callback if there is no subcommand.  So your group would be

```
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def autorole(self, ctx):
    exists = dbinteraction.dbexec("SELECT role from autorole WHERE server_id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id))
    if (exists == None):
        em = discord.Embed(title="Autorole is disabled for this guild.", color=discord.Color(0xff0000))
    else:
        em = discord.Embed(title="Autorole is enabled for this guild.", color = discord.Color(0x32ff00))
        rol = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=exists)
        em.add_field(name="Current role:", value=rol.mention)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Edit:

From my comment below:

> Try changing the names of the subcommands to `_enabled` and `_disabled` and pass `name="enabled"` and `name="disabled"` to the `command` decorators. This is a guess, but sometimes names that the `Bot` class uses internally don't work properly when used as command names.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but it still has the same behavior: whether i use a subcommand or not, it's always the group's code that is executed

Comment: @Newe That's really weird.  Could you try `print(ctx.invoked_subcommand)` to see what that's being populated with?

Comment: It returns None in all cases

Comment: Yes, that's the weird part

Comment: Try changing the names of the subcommands to `_enabled` and `_disabled` and pass `name="enabled"` `name="disabled"` to the `command` decorators. This is a guess, but sometimes names that the `Bot` uses internally don't work properly when used as command names.

Comment: Seems like this was it, i'm seeing what i want in the shell now. Thanks a lot!